# Divide text file to display each of its line on different forms

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to divide so that a uploaded textfile data is displayed on different textboxes/listboxes. Each line of the textfile is to be divided. 
For example:

Lets say a textfile have this content(one value per line):

> Kevin
>
> Simon
>
> John

Later I want to display each line of the textfile on different forms, for example:

> Textbox1 displays line 1(which will be Kevin)
>
> Textbox2 displays line 2(which will be Simon)
>
> Listbox1 displays line 3 (which will be John)

I'm wondering if this is possible and if so could you give an example.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

How do I add a couple of textfile lines to a listbox? 
I tried this but it doesnt add to the listView

```
 public void OpenFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            string line = "";
            int index = 0;
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    index++;
                    if (index == 1)
                        InvoiceNumbertxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 2)
                        InvoiceDatetxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 3)
                        DueDatetxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 3 && index == 4 && index == 5 && index == 6 && index == 7 && index == 8)
                        PersonInfolst.Items.Add(line);
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Fixed it

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, because I'm not familiar with the process. I was wondering if anyone had experience doing what I want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something simple like:

```
string line = "";
int index = 0;
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("PathToFile"))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        index++;
        if(index == 1)
            Textbox1.Text = line;
        else if(index == 2)
            Textbox2.Text = line;
        else if(index == 3)
            Listbox1.Items.Add(line);
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. But is `index` really the `index` of the TextFile?

Comment: No, index is just a convenient flag (variable) to insert the lines in order, and not overlap multiple lines into the same control.